# Bump Map applique in Blender 2.8?

Tags: texturing, uv

I understand the principle of the thing, but being a novice I just can’t get the pieces together.

I’m modeling a LEGO brick, and want to add the raised logo on the tops of the studs.  I thought a height map would do the trick.

I found the logo in a PNG file.
I added a seam around the top (round) face of the stud and UV Unwrapped (just that face), and lined things up in the UV editor.

Now what?  I’ve tried feeding a Bump Map node to the Normal input of the Principled shader, and various ways of feeding information to the Bump Map node.  Nothing works.

Meanwhile, I tried using the Texture Paint mode, but it shows its own UV mapping unrelated to what I unwrapped, and does not seem to connect with the images I have available rather than painting something directly.

Please note that I’m using Version 2.8 Daily Build.  Old tutorials will not help; I already looked, and the UI and nodes just don’t line up, or uses the Texture Paint.  (Specifically, the video in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/128056/70598) is not useful for me.)

---

In this version, there is a “UV Map” node, not any “Map UV” node.  This one has a UV output but no inputs, and a field that can be left blank or choose “UVMap”.

Comment: Old tutorials should be fine so long as they are using Cycles, not Blender Internal. Eevee uses the same bump map nodes as Cycles, which has used said nodes for many years. See this answer, for example https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75017/how-does-the-bump-node-work

Answer (score 2):

[image: node graph]

Feed the “Image Texture” to “Bump Map” to the Normal input of the shader.
Be sure to set “Non-Color Data”.

**Be sure the 3D view is in LookDev or Rendered mode.**  The default when you open the Shading tab might be Shaded, which will not show this effect.

Color or Alpha:  Use the intensity (black/white is low/high or high/low), or use the Alpha channel (the transparency in a PNG file).

The Bump node is used to convert height to Normals.

Comment: Also note that bump maps don't create actual geometry, so it might be fine for the logo on top, but not the pegs themselves. You could try an actual displacement map, but that requires actual geometry to displace, so it's not cheap or well suited for sharp geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Is the image black and white? Bump maps are meant to be black and white. Also pay attention to the file type.

Comment: The Color is automatically taken as intensity; that is, it converts to grayscale if necessary.  What about file type?  Would some image file formats simply not work for this?  JPEG would have noise, but I would not expect it to simply stop working.